# Setting rsync --password-file option is not working

Tags: bash, rsync

I'm using `rsync` to repeatedly send a folder from source to destination. When using a straight `bash` command, it prompts for a password. In order to prevent the prompting of a password, I've made a simple `cpp` program that calls a `bash` script of `rsync` to repeatedly send the folder to the destination by doing `fork` and `exec`. I tried this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186224/403634%5D), but it returns an error:

```
sudo rsync $args --password-file=rsync_pass -avz /home/user/folder/checkpoints/$1 secondaryvm@192.xxx.xxx.xxx::checkpoints/$1

rsync: failed to connect to 192.xxx.xxx.xxx (192.xxx.xxx.xxx): Connection refused (111)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(127) [sender=3.1.3]
```

**Note:** I only want to use the `--password-file` option

I have checked that the `rsync` daemon is running on the destination side by running the command: `sudo systemctl status rsync`. Here's my `rsyncd.conf`

```
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
port = 12000

[files]
path = /home/public_rsync
comment = RSYNC FILES
read only = true
timeout = 300
```

How do I get this working?

Comment: You could use public key authentication if you don't want to enter a password, no need for a daemon. [Edit] your question and add your `/etc/rsyncd.conf`. Are `auth users` and `secrets file` defined and properly setup?

Comment: The connection is being refused. This means either that the service is not running (on the standard port), or that there is a firewall somewhere on or between client and server rejecting such connections.

Comment: @Freddy where are these auth users and secrets file present?

Comment: @roaima how can i check that?

Comment: @roaima `sudo systemctl status rsync` on backup side

Comment: @Freddy have a look at the updated question.

Comment: Your command references the module `checkpoints` but your configuration defines `files`

Comment: @roaima what difference will that make

Comment: If you try to reference a module that's not been defined you won't be able to access any files. (Not a reason for "connection refused", but relevant nevertheless.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection was refused because you were using a non-standard rsync port, see the comments by user roaima.

For simplicity, I expect user `public_rsync` with home directory `/home/public_rsync` exists on the destination host (192.xxx.xxx.xxx, where the daemon is running) and the service is not blocked by your firewall.

Start with this sample `/etc/rsyncd.conf` (passwords are enabled later):

```
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsync.log

[checkpoints]
path = /home/public_rsync/checkpoints
comment = RSYNC FILES
read only = false
uid = public_rsync
gid = public_rsync
#auth users = secondaryvm
#secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
timeout = 300
```

Explanation:

- remove `port = 12000` to use default port 873
- change module name from `[files]` to `[checkpoints]`
- change the path to the module directory to `/home/public_rsync/checkpoints`
- change `read only = true` to `false` to be able to push files to the server
- add `uid` / `gid` to use this username / group when transferring files

Then restart the server:

```
sudo systemctl restart rsync
```

---

**1. Test `rsync` on the destination host as user `public_rsync`**

1. List all listable modules with `rsync localhost::`, it should return the module name and the description:

   ```
   public_rsync@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:~$ rsync localhost::
   checkpoints      RSYNC FILES
   ```
2. Create directory `checkpoints` and a test file in this directory:

   ```
   public_rsync@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:~$ mkdir ~/checkpoints
   public_rsync@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:~$ echo helloworld > ~/checkpoints/helloworld.txt
   ```
3. List all files of our module:

   ```
   public_rsync@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:~$ rsync localhost::checkpoints
   drwxrwxr-x          4,096 2020/10/30 18:26:01 .
   -rw-rw-r--             11 2020/10/30 18:26:01 helloworld.txt
   ```

---

**2. Test `rsync` from the source host, make sure pull/push are working**

1. Test pull:

   ```
   $ rsync 192.xxx.xxx.xxx::checkpoints/helloworld.txt /tmp/
   $ cat /tmp/helloworld.txt
   helloworld
   ```
2. Test push:

   ```
   $ rsync /tmp/helloworld.txt 192.xxx.xxx.xxx::checkpoints/helloworld_push.txt
   ```
3. List files of module `checkpoints` again:

   ```
   $ rsync 192.xxx.xxx.xxx::checkpoints
   drwxrwxr-x          4,096 2020/10/30 18:29:06 .
   -rw-rw-r--             11 2020/10/30 18:26:01 helloworld.txt
   -rw-r--r--             11 2020/10/30 18:29:06 helloworld_push.txt
   ```

---

**3. Enable authentication**

Now that we know `rsync` works as expected, enable authentication on the destination host:

1. Create text file `/etc/rsyncd.secrets` with username and password for user `secondaryvm` (the username is arbitrary, no user account needed):

   ```
   user@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:~$ sudo tee /etc/rsyncd.secrets > /dev/null <<'EOF'
   secondaryvm:12345
   EOF
   user@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:~$ sudo chmod 600 /etc/rsyncd.secrets
   ```
2. Uncomment `auth users` and `secrets file` in `/etc/rsyncd.conf`, restart the server:

   ```
   user@192.xxx.xxx.xxx:~$ sudo systemctl restart rsync
   ```

---

**4. Test authentication (from source host)**

Connecting without credentials should not be possibly any more, you're supposed to enter a password:

```
$ rsync 192.xxx.xxx.xxx::checkpoints
Password:
@ERROR: auth failed on module checkpoints
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1675) [Receiver=3.1.3]
```

Provide username and password for the connection, e.g.

```
$ echo '12345' > rsync_pass
$ chmod 600 rsync_pass
$ rsync --password-file=rsync_pass secondaryvm@192.xxx.xxx.xxx::checkpoints
```

If anything doesn't work, add verbosity with option `-v` and check the daemon log `/var/log/rsync.log`.

Comment: sorry i didn't checked this for some days. I followed the public key authentication answers on some pages. But what is happening now is it is unable to send some files which are permission protected.  and throws this error: `rsync: send_files failed to open "/home/usr/...../checkpoints/246/descriptors.json": Permission denied (13)`

Comment: public/private key process doesn't require passwords for transmission. but for these files it requires `sudo` and requires user to input password of destination

Comment: Make sure that the files are readable by the rsync user (you could use a group for that), directories should also have the executable bit set.

Comment: do you mean to say something like creating a group of users on the directory? What my scenario is there's repeatedly some folders are added into a directory, and i've to repeatedly send those folders to backup.

Comment: That was the idea, but if the files in that directory belong to different users/groups that doesn't make sense.
You could create an entry in your `/etc/sudoers` file to call your script with passwordless `sudo`, see [unix.stackexchange.com/a/229653/332764](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229653/332764) for an example and replace username/path to the script.
Or create a script with passwordless `sudo` to change ownership/permissions on the files before you call your sync script as normal user. Use public key authentication or the version with password file from my answer.

Comment: Hi, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229653/332764) solution is not working.

Comment: Please ask a new question. It's difficult to help in the comments section and the permissions problem is not related to the original question. You can add a link to refer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: sorry I know comments could not give you better clarity. head over to here pls. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64691809/sudoless-passwordless-script